# No sound through HDMI cable

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

As the title suggests, I'm not able to reproduce any sound on my external TV through the HDMI cable.
To note that starting using the same notebook with Windows does not give any kind of problem.

I've tried all the solution found so far on the web, namely

- `speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3` and/or `speaker-test -D hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0 -c 2`
- Upgrading alsa driver to the latest version (now I have oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms:amd64 0.201702010732~ubuntu14.04.1 installed)
- Use pulseaudio, alsamixer or the default sound manager to switch to the HDMI output port
- `pulseaudio -k` to restart the pulseaudio daemon
- adding my user to various groups with `usermod -a -G audio,pulse,pulse-access,video,voice $USER`

but, as said, nothing changed.

Here is some useful output

> dpkg -l | grep alsa
>       ii  alsa-base                                                   1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4                                all          ALSA driver configuration files
>       ii  alsa-utils                                                  1.0.27.2-1ubuntu2                                   amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
>       ii  bluez-alsa:amd64                                            4.101-0ubuntu13.1                                   amd64        Bluetooth ALSA support
>       ii  gnome-alsamixer                                             0.9.7~cvs.20060916.ds.1-5                           amd64        ALSA sound mixer for GNOME
>       ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64                                    0.10.36-1.1ubuntu2                                  amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
>       ii  libsox-fmt-alsa:amd64                                       14.4.1-3ubuntu1                                     amd64        SoX alsa format I/O library

```
>lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

>sudo lshw | grep -A9 "Audio"
 description: Audio device
 product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
 vendor: Intel Corporation
 physical id: 1b
 bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
 version: 04
 width: 64 bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
 configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
 resources: irq:47 memory:f1610000-f1613fff

>aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: 92HD91BXX Analog [92HD91BXX Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

N.B.: I don't know if it can be an issue, but I have two subdevices: 1/1.

```
>pacmd list-cards
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
>>> 1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 5
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf1610000 irq 47"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1e20"
        device.product.name = "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Input (priority 60, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Output (priority 6000, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Duplex (priority 6060, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analogue Stereo Input (priority 5460, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
        alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-microphone-internal: Internal Microphone (priority 8900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-microphone: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

---

### Some images

... from PulseAudio Volume Control ...
[image: Configuration]
[image: OutputDevices]

... Gnome Alsa mixer ...
[image: Alsa]

... and the dafault sound manager
[image: SoundManager]

I don't know what else to try and any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. In my case, the tv that's connected to my nVidia card is listed as "available: no" so it doesn't show on the sound manager, but it does in pavucontrol (where it says it's unplugged).
The difference is that I'm using an nVidia card, and you're using intel.